# What is the difference equation or system function of this system?

Tags: transfer-function, system-identification

[image]

I am having trouble figuring out what the difference equation or the system function for this system is? **Here ''R'' represents the unit delay.** The fact that the delay is not part of the feedback loop is confusing me.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal after the summer is $e[n] = x[n]+y[n]$. In the feed-forward line a delay of 3 units is applied. Thus we have $$y[n] = \mathcal{R}(\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{R} (e[n]))) = x[n-3]+ y[n-3]$$. The equivalent transfer function is :$$ H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{z^{-3}}{1-z^{-3}}$$